# Magento2.3.3 Review on homepage

Tags: magento2

```
namespace Magento\Review\Block\Product\ReviewRenderer;

if ($product->getRatingSummary() === null) {
        $this->reviewSummaryFactory->create()->appendSummaryDataToObject(
            $product,
            $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
        );
}
```

this is Magento2.3.3 review renderer Block code its rating starts not shwoing on home page but when i comment this line

```
//  if ($product->getRatingSummary() === null) {
```

its shows on home page is it right solution can any one guide or its a Magento2.3.3 bug

Answer (score 0):

can you tried to put '==' instead of '===' cause I read here https://github.com/sentientmachine/php_equality_charts

if not then you have to try `if(!empty($product->getRatingSummary())){`

Comment: if(!empty($product->getRatingSummary())){ this worked but it is magento2.3.3

Comment: magento 2.3.3 well support php :)

Comment: then what this mean ===  this is core code of magento2.3.3

Comment: if ($product->getRatingSummary() === null || !empty($product->getRatingSummary())) {

Comment: if ($product->getRatingSummary() === null || !empty($product->getRatingSummary())) { this is fine? because its working

Comment: Yes. it's also fine here your are putting 'OR' condition , I think you have to use only one here '!empty($product->getRatingSummary())'